# Make a recurring payment button in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I want to add a Subscription button in my site for recurring payment in PayPal, with HTML and PHP.

I have used the code given here https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside , but for a developer test account instead. But I cannot test it, and check if this works or not.

Is there something I have to set in my developer account? 
I use also a callback function because I want to inform my database for a payment every month. For the first payment the callback is called. But how can I check with the test account if it will work the second month too? And which is the variable I get in $_POST so as to be notified that every month the payment has been done successfully or not?
So could you please help me, or send me any link that have some code examples about it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are sure you add `input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"`? This field in your subscription html code because it returns a list of parameters in Post method to your return page